# Java applet is very slow in newest version of mac Firefox

Tags: java, macos, firefox, applet

I'm running a Java applet, made in processing, as part of a web application. It's a simple applet that has bouncing balls that move around the applet.

This runs at normal speed in Windows Firefox 5.0 and Mac Firefox 3.6. It also works perfectly in the newest version of Safari. (both Safari and Firefox were run on the same computer) However, on Firefox 5.0.1, the balls "jump" from place to place, rather than moving continuously.

Is there a commonly known reason that this might happen? Can I do anything to insure good performance on mac firefox?

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this [example applet](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway) works correctly on Firefox 5.0.1. You might verify that your [Processing](http://processing.org/) is up to date. If you add any Swing components to your `PApplet`, verify that you use the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) thread correctly.